# JS: Qué diferencia hay entre parseFloat( variable, 10) vs (1 * variable)?

Tags: javascript

He visto que en los ejemplos, no sólo aquí sino en la literatura y guías de javascript, cuando hay que castear un string compuesto de puros números, se usa:

```
var foo = '12345.10';

var numeric_foo = parseFloat(foo, 10);
```

He encontrado varias ocurrencias en mi código en donde simplemente hice

```
var numeric_foo = 1 * foo;
```

Y eso obviamente tiene cara de ser un atajo poco elegante. Pero no entiendo bien ¿En qué caso el segundo tipo de casteo me puede dar un valor  inconsistente?

Probé aplicar ambas maneras a strings que contenían números, pero ambos me dieron NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La diferencia como tal es que el `parseFloat`, te corta el texto al momento de hacer el parseo si se encuentra con un caracter no deseado, ya que si tu primer caracter es numero, esta cadena sera interpretada como int ejemplo:

```
var foo = '1 Lore Ipsum';
var numeric_foo = parseFloat(foo, 10);
console.log(numeric_foo); //Imprime 1

var numeric_foo2 = 1 * foo;
console.log(numeric_foo2); //Imprime NaN
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
var foo = '123451%%%545454';
var numeric_foo = parseFloat(foo, 10);
console.log(numeric_foo); // IMprime 123451

var numeric_foo2 = 1 * foo;
console.log(numeric_foo2); //Imprime NaN
```

El unico caracter aceptado es el punto (.) ya que es separador de decimales:

```
var foo = '123451.545454';
var numeric_foo = parseFloat(foo, 10);
console.log(numeric_foo); //imprime 123451.545454

var numeric_foo2 = 1 * foo;
console.log(numeric_foo2); //imprime 123451.545454
```

Mientras que `1 * foo` asegurara que foo sea un integer/float y tratara de hacer la operacion, por eso el NaN.

Adicionalmente se nota que el parseFloat trata de no reventar el codigo al momento de ver algo como esto `var foo = '1 Lore Ipsum';` Cosa que en lo particular no esta del todo bien, ya que en lo particular en una ocasion pasada perdi mucho timpo por parsear un string en numero que no era valido y el parseFloat lo tomaba como que si lo era.

Comment: Y ahora estoy viendo que parseInt hace lo mismo! Algo me dice que tengo muchos NaNes que debuggear.